# how can I delete mysql with the root?

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

I forgot my mysql root password and tried everything I found on the internet to recover the password and nothing worked. I don't have any important databases. I want to remove it completely and reinstall it fresh so I can create a new root password.

Is it possible and how?

macOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. First, connect to the MySQL database as the root user:**

```
mysql -u root -p
```

If root does not have access to MySQL on your machine, you can use sudo mysql

**2. Enter the password when prompted and hit Enter. A MySQL shell loads.**

**3. Find the exact name of the user you want to remove by running a command that lists users from the MySQL server:**

```
SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
```

**4. The output displays all users. Locate the name you want to remove, in our case it is MySQLtest. Replace username in the following command with your user:**

```
DROP USER 'username'@'host';
```